# Redshift/Java: SQL execute hangs and never returns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

The application that im working on runs a sequence of queries on AWS Redshift. Some of the queries take longer to execute due to the data volume.

The queries seem to finish on Redshift when i check the execution details on the server. However, the java application seems to hang indefinitely without throwing any exception or even terminating.

Here's the code that executes the query.

```
private void execSQLStrings(String[] queries, String dataset, String dbType) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;

    if (dbType.equals("redshift")) {
        conn=getRedshiftConnection();
    } else if (dbType.equals("rds")){
        conn=getMySQLConnection();
    }

    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

    String qry=null;
    debug("Query Length: " + queries.length);
    for (int ii=0;ii<queries.length;++ii) {
        qry=queries[ii];

        if (dataset != null) {
            qry=qry.replaceAll("DATASET",dataset);
        }

        debug(qry);
        stmt.execute(qry);
    }
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

I cant post the query that im running at the moment but it has multiple table joins and group by conditions and its an 800m row table. The query takes about 7~8 mins to complete on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the DSN Timeout and/ or KeepAlive settings to make sure that your connections stay alive.
Refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html

Comment: Thanks ! this definitely helped.